# Best technique for prolonged study

Tags: exams

According to my daily schedule I need to study for long hourd each day including weekdays and weekends sometimes I find that this is just too much sometimes.

What are some methods to get the optimal efficiency while studying.

Can you suggest me some great tips for effective study or in general give me some tips and techniques which I  should follow so that I can get the maximum output for my input.

It's actually for an exam , which is after 1 year and the syllabus is vast ( 2 years of schooling worth of syllabus) and of  Maths(Basic algebra, Calculus, Co-ordinate Geometry ) Physics(mechanics electrodynamics, modern physics and optics) And Chemistry (basic organic inorganic,physical) (about 30 chapters each)

So also some methods to remember what I study for long time might be really helpful :)

Comment: Who set this schedule? It doesn't sound sustainable.

Comment: I don't know of anyone who can get anything near 13 really good hours of learning in a day.

Comment: Let's just say long study hours....Ways for optimal study for long study hours

Answer (score 2):

Since you have tagged it exams, let me offer some hints. I don't know what subject, so I'll assume something like math or CS.

The best way to study for exams is not to have to do it at all. That is to say, make sure that you know the answers to most of the questions likely to come up in an exam long before the date of the exam.

In order to learn something deeply, you need to use repetition and feedback. The repetition means doing exercises, working problems, writing programs, etc. In other fields it might mean writing on topics of the course. The feedback part means that you have to get someone to comment on your work on the exercises. Normally that is the professor grading your work, but you can also use study groups to get feedback from peers (and give it to them as well). For some things you can use some form of automation to get feedback.

But if your main technique is memorization it will likely be ineffective. It will be ineffective for most people, at least. It would be possible to memorize something like the complete text of a calculus book, for example, while actually understanding almost nothing and also not being able to solve anything beyond the easiest problems. Practice - reinforcement - and feedback.

And you also want to give you brain a rest. You aren't a machine that works efficiently as long as it has fuel. Your brain needs periods of rest to actually allow it to synthesize the ideas that you are trying to learn. Pushing it constantly leads to less and less efficient working. Take a nap, or use physical activity to recharge.

Comment: 1) I couldn't find tags 2) It's actually for an exam , which I have 1 year to prepare from and the syllabus is vast ( 2 years of schooling worth of syllabus ) 3) Maths Physics And Chemistry ( about 30 chapters each)

Comment: Thank You Dr.Buffy

Comment: For standardized exams, forming a study group might be a good option.

Comment: They often turn unproductive because either the people you are with ae not competitive , so waste your time by doing random things , or if are equally or more competitive, become selfish, and don't want the other to grow.... As you are ultimately their competitor. Competition is fierce (1.5 million people, being in top 300 is what you want)

Comment: Here is a weird thought. Suppose the other four people you might have formed a study group with do so without you and they wind up among the 300. Maybe it is the thought of competition that is hurting you and leading you to unproductive behavior.